# All-in-one collaborative portal

Tags: collaboration

I've done crazy amounts of research, and so far I've only found one decent platform that provides everything I need: Bitrix24. However, their time-tracking feature is reserved for their most premium plan, which is $200 a month. We're a really small outfit and can't afford that. There are also some concerns I have with the quality of their product.

Does anyone know of any online platforms or intranets that provide ALL of the following in a single solution? I don't want to "integrate" multiple platforms.

- File syncing, like Dropbox. Not just manual uploads, but desktop sync.
- Task management
- Time tracking (with a start/stop button, not just manual entry)
- IM/Video conferencing
- Decent price / GB storage, preferably < $50 per month for ideally 100GB or more.
- Meeting scheduling, with per-person availability (optional)
- Social network-style feeds and posts (optional)
- Good Agile support (optional)
- Git repository integration (optional)

Comment: If you are a small company (and want to grow) expect to have changing requirements soon. I doubt that you will find a solution witch such a long list of requirements, that fits your needs today as well as in some years. Task management and time tracking seems to be the only thing that should go together, but for the other requirements, why not take individual approaches?

Comment: Well, we have been taking individual approaches, for a few years now. It's a pain to manage. As a remote team, it's hard enough to get my guys to use a single platform consistently and correctly, let alone half a dozen. With Bitrix24, they only have to check one place and download one app for communication, file syncing, tasks, time tracking, etc. Bitrix24 really does offer almost all of the above features, so I'm alright with sticking with them for the time being. Just wanted to know if there were any real competitors to them out there.